# Show that $a_n>0$ for all sufficiently large $n$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Let $F_n, G$ be distribution functions on $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $F_n(a_nx+b_n)\to G(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in c(G)$ where $c(G):=\{x\in\mathbb R:G(x)-G(x-)=0\}$. Here $a_n,b_n$ are real sequences. Show that $a_n>0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

I do not understand one thing: what is the problem if $a_n<0$? We are not given that $F_n$ converge in distribution to $G$. But I do understand that if $a_n>0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then $(X_n-b_n)/a_n\to G$ in distribution.

However I fail to understand how it affects if $a_n<0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\leq x^\prime$ be two continuity points of $G$. 
If there were a subsequence 
  with $a_{n(k)}\leq 0$ for all $k$, then 
$a_{n(k)}x^\prime +b_{n(k)}\leq a_{n(k)}x +b_{n(k)}$ and hence
$F_{n(k)}(a_{n(k)}x^\prime +b_{n(k)})
\leq F_{n(k)}(a_{n(k)}x +b_{n(k)}).$
Letting $k\to\infty$ gives $G(x^\prime)\leq G(x)$
so that $G$ is a *non-increasing* function, instead of non-decreasing. 
This contradicts the fact that $G$ is a distribution function.

Comment: Oh thank you. It was this simple!!